# Excel Macro (Separate Data)

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel macro that can separate and save files per column. My problem is that I cannot make it work with large number of rows (60,000).

What should I change in my VBA code below to make it work?

[image: Separate Data Form]

```
 Dim MyFile, NewFile As Variant
  Dim sort_data As String
  Dim last_row, tfiles, start_row, ktr As Integer
    
  'Capture errors
  On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
  
  'Check for complete data
  If (Separate.file_open.Value = False And Separate.Filename _
   = "") Or Separate.first = "" Or Separate.last = "" Or _
   Separate.sort = "" Or Separate.left_column = "" Or _
   Separate.right = "" Then
    MsgBox "Insufficient data.", 16, "Warning!"
    Exit Sub
  End If
  
  'Turn application alerts off
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  
  'Open filename if necessary
  If Separate.file_open.Value = False Then
    Workbooks.Open Separate.Filename
  End If
  
  'Get current workbook name
  MyFile = left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, Len(ActiveWorkbook.Name) _
           - 4)
  
  'Get last row of data
  For last_row = Separate.last + 1 To 1048576
    If Range(Separate.sort & last_row).Value = "" Then
      Exit For
    End If
  Next last_row
  
  
  'Sort data
  Range(Separate.left_column & Separate.last, Separate.right & last_row).Select
  Selection.sort Key1:=Range(Separate.sort & Separate.last + 1), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=True, _
    OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to:

```
Dim last_row, tfiles, start_row, ktr As Integer
```

`Integer` mentioned in the script having a max number 32,767. You can use `Long` instead of `Integer`.

```
    Dim last_row, tfiles, start_row, ktr As Long
```

Comment: 2,147,483,647, larger then excel max row number